# Never seen and can't find out such a weird sign encoding in URL

Tags: unicode, urlencode

Does somebody ever seen such a sign encoding in an URL: `&%23x3F;`?

It seems to be like encoded `'`, but it looks more like an apostrophe from Word. And `'` looks encoded like `%27`, `%E2%80%98` or `%E2%80%99`. you can see it live here:

> http://ow.ly/LhPyt

Which ends up here:

> http://www.hotelreservierung.de/angebot/St-James&%23x3F;s-Club-Morgan-Bay-Saint-Lucia/Hotel-4432957

The question is: what sign is this exactly? I can't find it in any unicode table! I thought first, it could be a combination

Comment: It's the question mark character, first HTML-encoded, and then (incompletely) URL-encoded. Maybe it was a smart quote once, but if so it has gone through some unrecoverable mangling.

Comment: i thought so firstly too, because a part of the string is an encoded # character. But it isn't! I tried then to change encoded sign to decoded and got 404

Comment: @double-beep stop editing the question! You are screwing up my answer, and you are not even replacing the link with the correct URL for the question asked. I'm aware of SO's policy on banning url shorteners, but this question predates that policy, and I don't think it applies in this situation anyway since the question is related to the url that a url shortener is forwarding to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`%23` is the url-encoded form of the `#` character.  So the URL contains an encoded string value of `&#x3F;`.

An HTML entity can be expressed in one of three formats:

`&<name>;`  `&#<decimal>;`  `&#x<hex>;`

In this case, the URL contains a hex-encoded HTML entity, where `0x3F` is the hex value for the `?` character.

The URL you provided:

> http://ow.ly/LhPyt

As well as this direct URL:

> http://www.hotelreservierung.de/angebot/St-James's-Club-Morgan-Bay-Saint-Lucia/Hotel-4432957

Both respond with an HTTP redirect to this URL:

> http://www.hotelreservierung.de/angebot/St-James&%23x3F;s-Club-Morgan-Bay-Saint-Lucia/Hotel-4432957

```
GET /LhPyt HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: ow.ly
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http:// goo.gl/8vb7n8
Connection: close
Content-Length: 0

GET /8vb7n8 HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Host: goo.gl
Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Mon, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Date: Fri, 10 Apr 2015 16:59:34 GMT
Location: http://www.hotelreservierung.de/angebot/St-James&%23x3F;s-Club-Morgan-Bay-Saint-Lucia/Hotel-4432957
Content-Encoding: gzip
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Content-Length: 240
Server: GSE
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Age: 83
Alternate-Protocol: 80:quic,p=0.5
```

```
GET /angebot/St-James's-Club-Morgan-Bay-Saint-Lucia/Hotel-4432957 HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: www.hotelreservierung.de
DNT: 1
Connection: Keep-Alive

HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 10 Apr 2015 17:01:07 GMT
Server: Apache/2
Provided-Host: hrslave03
Set-Cookie: _hrlnkflghtl2=a%3A1%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A12%3A%22Hrlnkflghtl1%22%3B%7D; expires=Sun, 10-May-2015 17:01:07 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: _hrhtldtlnwdsgn2=a%3A1%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A16%3A%22Hrhtldtlnwdsgn2b%22%3B%7D; expires=Sun, 10-May-2015 17:01:07 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: _hrstrtpgnwfrm=a%3A1%3A%7Bi%3A0%3Bs%3A14%3A%22Hrstrtpgnwfrm4%22%3B%7D; expires=Sun, 10-May-2015 17:01:07 GMT; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: mDhBeFyD=00; Expires=Sat, 11-Apr-2015 17:01:07 GMT; Path=/
Location: /angebot/St-James&%23x3F;s-Club-Morgan-Bay-Saint-Lucia/Hotel-4432957
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 20
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html
```

Notice the `Location` header in both responses.

In the first case, the browser is simply navigating to the new URL that `goo.gl` told it to go to.

In the second case, the browser is transmitting the `'` character as-is in its `GET` request and is then being redirected to a new URL that contains `&%23x3F;` instead.  So it is the `hotelreservierung.de` server itself that is deciding to encode the `'` character as `&%23x3F;` in its URL.  It is not the browser doing that.

Comment: Do you know, why if i replace this encoded character with question mark i get 404, but if i replace it with ' and press enter, the browser encodes the ' back to &%23x3F; and loads the page without error?

Comment: An unencoded `?` is a reserved character in a URL, it separates the URL's path from its query string. So if the URL has an unencoded `?` in it, you are changing the semantics of the URL, and that can easily cause a 404 error. But there is no way any browser would encode a user-typed `'` character as `&%23x3F;` in a URL. Characters in URLs are not html-encoded before being url-encoded.

Comment: try the example url i cited above in initial post: there is namely the case where if you type manually `'` instead of `&%23x3F;` it will be automatically encoded by browser back to `&%23x3F;`

Comment: It is not the browser that is encoding the character.  It is the target server instead.  I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! it should be a server misconfiguration, if `'` is converted into such a weird character... Could you please delete the origin urls (at least host names) from your answer update or mask them?

Comment: The "origin urls" and their hostnames are publically accessible, especially to anyone who just looks at their browser's address bar. And there is no sensitive data in the HTTP headers I showed. There is no reason to mask anything in this answer.